# Windows 7 Desktop without location sensor

Tags: c#, .net, location

I'm writing a windows 7 desktop C# app and I need to write code when there is a location sensor. I have this:

```
            public string check(string stop)
            {
            GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
            watcher.Start();

            watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);

            return null;

            }

        static void watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Status)
            {
                case GeoPositionStatus.Initializing:
                    Console.WriteLine("Working on location fix");
                    break;

                case GeoPositionStatus.Ready:
                    Console.WriteLine("Have location");
                    break;

                case GeoPositionStatus.NoData:
                    Console.WriteLine("No data");
                    break;

                case GeoPositionStatus.Disabled:
                    Console.WriteLine("Disabled");
                    break;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("GO");
        }
```

This is really just to see if it grabs the latitude and longitude, but I don't have a sensor and I just want to know, will this work if a laptop does have a sensor? I can't afford to get a sensor yet so I would like to have the code and move on until I can aquire one. Also, I need to stop the geocoordinatewatcher when the user logs out, so since I cant stop this in a different function, if I start another and stop that one will that stop all?These functions are called from a webapge and there are no buttons on my form. The function called when a user logs out will be stop();. And just in case someone wanted to suggest it, I can't use GeoSense.

Comment: this code is correct ! if it is giving "No Data" it means that there is no GPS sensor in the device. In case if a device is having GPS and it is turned off , the status shall show disabled. this code shall work properly ! try it on some windows tablet

Answer (score 0):

Old question but here goes anyway:

I think your answer is not a problem with the sensor but with the scope of the watcher variable.  You start the watcher then register for the event and then your watcher losses scope.

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

public string check(string stop)
{
   watcher.Start();...
```